# jquery accordion - keeps hiding parent element?

Tags: jquery, accordion

Well, I fixed my original question by including  after the closing  tags, but now, those links won't open?

So, basically, in the html below, I'm trying so that only the services section slides open, but I want the h3 tags to open those links...

```
<div id="sp-accordion">
    <h3><a href="/?page_id=3">Home</a></h3><div></div>
    <h3><a href="/?page_id=2">About Us</a></h3><div></div>
    <h3><a href="#"> Services</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p><a href="/?page_id=16">S1</a></p>
        <p><a href="/?page_id=14">S2</a></p>
        <p><a href="/?page_id=20">S3</a></p>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="/?page_id=9">Contact Us</a></h3><div></div>
    <h3><a href="/?page_id=5">Tips</a></h3><div></div>
    <h3><a href="/?page_id=108">Jobs</a></h3><div></div>
    <h3><a href="/?page_id=131">Newsletter</a></h3><div></div>
</div>
```

The accordion works, insomuch that when you click on the h3 tag, the container slides open, however, when it slides open, it hides the h3 before it.  So, in the html below, when I click on "Services" the div beneath it slides open, but the About Us h3 disappears...

This is the html:

```
<div id="sp-accordion">
    <h3><a href="/?page_id=3">Home</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="/?page_id=2">About Us</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="#"> Services</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p><a href="/?page_id=16">S1</a></p>
        <p><a href="/?page_id=14">S2</a></p>
        <p><a href="/?page_id=20">S3</a></p>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="/?page_id=9">Contact Us</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="/?page_id=5">Tips</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="/?page_id=108">Jobs</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="/?page_id=131">Newsletter</a></h3>
</div>
```

I'm using jquery ui, so the jquery is just this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sp-accordion").accordion({autoHeight:false});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have links inside your content. Please try this

"If you have links inside the accordion content and use a-elements as headers, add a class to them and use that as the header, eg. header: 'a.header'."

This is from the JQuery UI doco.

Hope this helps :)